# Read From Local Storage Function Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to Android Studio and I've looked around everywhere for clues on how to write/read data when using Kotlin in Android Studio. I put together the following function, but the app crashes each time I run it. What am I doing wrong here?

private fun readFromFile(fileName: String): String? {

```
    var myData: String? = ""
    var fileInputStream: FileInputStream? = null

    try {
        fileInputStream = openFileInput(fileName)
        var inputStreamReader: InputStreamReader = InputStreamReader(fileInputStream)

        if(inputStreamReader != null) {
            val bufferedReader: BufferedReader = BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
            val stringBuilder: StringBuilder = StringBuilder()
            while (run {
                    myData = bufferedReader.readLine()
                    myData
                } != null){
                stringBuilder.append("\n").append(myData)
            }
            inputStreamReader.close()
            myData = stringBuilder.toString()
        }

    } catch (e: IOException){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return myData
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

2022-02-23 20:12:49.309 2927-2927/com.example.mydrink E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mydrink, PID: 2927
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mydrink/com.example.mydrink.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
32"
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
32"
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:604)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
at com.example.mydrink.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:29)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
... 11 more

Comment: You should share your crash report

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this actually does work as intended. I had an issue where I was converting the output value to an integer and the code was not liking how I was doing it. So this code does work to read from file.